# How to redirect complete outgoing phone's traffic to a proxy server?

Tags: proxy

How to redirect entire phone traffic (including all apps) to a proxy **(with out rooting the phone)**

We are developing a parental control app for Android, in that we have requirement to capture all out going traffic from Android phone for categorization.
Is there a way to achieve this in Android **with out rooting the phone**.

Thanks,
Gopi.

Comment: Related: [Automatic system-wide proxy](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/50643/16575)

Comment: [Why is not all traffic captured from my device when routing through proxy?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219280/218526)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are describing a VPN (virtual private network). A VPN directs all traffic (whether http or other tcp/ip protocols) through a specific server, usually with the intent to encrypt traffic between the device and the VPN server.

However, encryption isn't necessary, and a VPN would have full control over routing, which means you could customize a VPN server to block specific requests. Or you could redirect requests to unsafe/undesirable websites to a 'block' page of your choosing.

Almost all android devices have VPN capabilities built-in. You should look into that technology. In order to force the user to go through the VPN, you will need an app that can be set as a device admin (a built-in, almost-root privilege that prevents the app from being removed) that would also set the VPN to be always on.

See this Android.SE [question and answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13074/force-vpn-usage?rq=1) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for your valuable answer.                     Is there any other possible solution than VPN? Since Android 4.0 they included an API called VpnService, through this I can directs all traffic but I see some challenges in that approach. Below are the challenges I see,                           - User action is required to create a VPN connection.
- A system-managed notification (in notification bar) is shown during the lifetime of a VPN connection. 
- A system-managed dialog gives the information of the current VPN connection. It also provides a button to disconnect.

Comment: How can we overcome above mentioned challenges?Any body have any idea on this please help me. We are doing this for an ISP not for individual users.Thanks in advance.  Thanks,Gopi.

Answer (score 1):

By design proxy isn't to be set system-wide, it's to be used on per-connection basis by every app individually. However it's possible to enforce the proxy on whole traffic e.g. by modifying routing table or NAT rules at OSI Layer 2 or 3; either by rooting the phone (which you don't want to) or making use of VPN (as answered by [Stephen Schrauger](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/11190/stephen-schrauger)). However you can't redirect all TCP/UDP traffic to a proxy server, there are limitations. For details see [Why proxy set on Android does not work when used as hotspot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217848/218526)