# How to redirect all web requests from hosts connected to hotspot to a local web server?

Tags: wi-fi, browser, wifi-hotspot, proxy, web-server

I literally have the same question as found in this post: [How to redirect complete outgoing phone's traffic to a proxy server?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56373/how-to-redirect-complete-outgoing-phones-traffic-to-a-proxy-server[.][1])

I have an Android phone acting as a hotspot server (using KWS). I am able to connect another device and access my little webpage by typing `192.168.43.1:8080` into the URL search of my browser, so no problem there.

However, I would like for all requests by connected devices to be redirected to my webpage.

The answer in the linked question suggests running two DNS servers using the Server's Ultimate app. My only hesitation is that it is not free, and the 'free' version is a 7 day trial. 
I have tried another app called "Set DNS," which seems promising, but it will not recognize my hotspot as a network; it keeps waiting for me to connect to something.

**QUESTIONS:**

- Can I simply change the `/system/etc/hosts` file as mentioned in the linked post?
- Would I add a line such as: `192.168.43.1:8080    *`?
- If not, must I purchase Server's Ultimate, or is there another alternative?

**PS:** This is for an advertisement. The webpage is to be static and informative (no malicious activity).

Answer (score 1):

***NOTE:*** Solution suggested here requires root access.

> I would like for all requests by connected devices to be redirected to my webpage

When you create hotspot, Android runs `dnsmasq` as DHCP/DNS server (up to Android 9). We can use this DNS server to resolve every domain to your desired IP address. Create file `/system/etc/dnsmasq.conf` and add the following option:

```
address=/#/192.168.43.1
```

See details in [manpage](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html). Start hotspot and test. Similarly you can use other DNS servers on your Android device e.g. [dnscrypt-proxy](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207647/218526).

You need to make sure that the connected hosts don't use some public DNS like `1.1.1.1`, instead must use DNS provided by DHCP i.e. IP address of Android device. Or redirect all DNS traffic to local DNS server:

```
~# iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p UDP --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to 53
```

**NOTE:**

For `http://example.com` request goes to `192.168.43.1:80` and for `https://example.com` it goes to `192.168.43.1:443`. However if you type `http://example.com/test.html` it requests page `192.168.43.1:80/test.html` which should exist, otherwise an error will be returned. An easy way is to configure your advertisement webpage as index page and default error page. For instance `index-file.names` and `server.error-handler` options on `lighttpd`.

---

> - Can I simply change the `/system/etc/hosts` file as mentioned in the linked post?
> - Would I add a line such as: `192.168.43.1:8080    *`?

`hosts` file is used by DNS resolvers which are usually part of main C library of OS. As far as I know the built-in resolvers on Android/Linux/Windows don't support wildcards, so the `*` trick won't work. Secondly, domain names are resolved to IP address (`192.168.43.1`) not ports (`:8080`). See below links for details on DNS.

Web browsers by default use port `80` for `http` requests. If you are running server on some other port, you have to mention the port on web browser. Or redirect all newly generated TCP traffic from port `80` to `8080`:

```
~# iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -m conntrack ! --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to 8080
```

---

**RELATED:**

- [How DNS works on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205740/218526)
- [How name resolutions works?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215878/218526)

Comment: I made an app uses similar solution mentioned by irfan.
It has very minimal UI and requires root permission. Check here: https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/guide-setup-fake-captive-portal-android-t4011689